# Is it possible to update only one field to Realm?

Tags: realm

Android Studio 3.2, Java 1.7, Realm 4.1.0

Here my pojo:

```
public class ImageFormats extends RealmObject {
    private ImageSource reference;
    private ImageSource average;
}


public class ImageSource extends RealmObject {
    private String url;
    private int width;
    private int height;
}
```

Here how I update `reference`

```
public void cascadeUpdate(Realm realm, ImageFormats that) {
        if (!EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.average, that.average)) {
            setAverage(that.average == null ? null : realm.copyToRealm(that.average));
        }
    }
```

Nice it work fine.

But I wan't to update **WHOLE** object `ImageSource`  because may change only one property, e.g. `url`

And I try to update to Realm only field that was changed.
So I try this:

```
public void cascadeUpdate(Realm realm, ImageSource that) {
        if (!EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.url, that.url)) {
            setUrl(that.url == null ? null : realm.copyToRealm(that.url)); // error here
        }
    }
```

But I get compile error:

```
error: no suitable method found for copyToRealm(String)
```

So, how I can update to Realm only changed field?

Comment: Get the object from the Realm and use the object's setter instead of `copyToRealm`

Comment: So this code is correct? - public void cascadeUpdate(Realm realm, ImageSource that) {
        if (!EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.url, that.url)) {
           setUrl(that.url);
        }
    }

Comment: Actually now that you mention it, the latest version should support ImportFlag on copyToRealmOrUpdate which should be able to do what you need.

Comment: (The latest version is 5.8.0, so I guess the right way for you IS to fetch the object and set it if it's not equal, so yeah)